# How do I round numbers inside of the multi row commenting function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a function to find the number and percent of the genders with Covid cases and I cant figure out how to round percentages in the `'''` multi row commenting function.

When ever I use the `"{0:.2f}"` rounding function, it gives me: "cannot switch from automatic field numbering to manual field specification"

How do I round the percentages in the `"""`? Or is there a better way to do it?

I need the function to **return**, not print the outputting result.

Also is there a way on how I could perhaps optimize the function/make shorter?

```
genders = ['Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot only specify with indexes a single format string value. All or none.

Either Do Not Specify Indexes:

```py
def list_gender(genders):
    f = genders.count('Female')  # counting from the list
    m = genders.count('Male')
    n_binary = genders.count('Non-Binary')
    other = genders.count('Other')
    trans = genders.count('Transgender')
    unknown = genders.count('Unknown')
    num_total = len(genders)
    female_percent = f / num_total * 100  # percentages
    male_percent = m / num_total * 100
    nonb_percent = n_binary / num_total * 100
    other_percent = other / num_total * 100
    trans_percent = trans / num_total * 100
    unknown_percent = unknown / num_total * 100
    string = '''
Female: {} cases {:.02f}
Male: {} cases {:.02f}
Non-Binary: {} cases {}   #Second bracket are the percentages
Other: {} cases {}
Transgender: {} cases {}
Unknown: {} cases {}
    '''.format(f, female_percent, m,
               male_percent, n_binary, nonb_percent,
               other, other_percent, trans, trans_percent,
               unknown, unknown_percent)

    return string
```

---

Or Specify All Indexes:

```py
def list_gender(genders):
    f = genders.count('Female')  # counting from the list
    m = genders.count('Male')
    n_binary = genders.count('Non-Binary')
    other = genders.count('Other')
    trans = genders.count('Transgender')
    unknown = genders.count('Unknown')
    num_total = len(genders)
    female_percent = f / num_total * 100  # percentages
    male_percent = m / num_total * 100
    nonb_percent = n_binary / num_total * 100
    other_percent = other / num_total * 100
    trans_percent = trans / num_total * 100
    unknown_percent = unknown / num_total * 100
    string = '''
Female: {0} cases {1:.02f}
Male: {2} cases {3:.02f}
Non-Binary: {4} cases {5}   #Second bracket are the percentages
Other: {6} cases {7}
Transgender: {8} cases {9}
Unknown: {10} cases {11}
    '''.format(f, female_percent, m,
               male_percent, n_binary, nonb_percent,
               other, other_percent, trans, trans_percent,
               unknown, unknown_percent)

    return string
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did it for the `male_percent`, but this is one method...

Without...

```
.format(f, female_percent, m, male_percent,  n_binary, nonb_percent, other, other_percent,trans, trans_percent, unknown, unknown_percent) 

Male: 2 cases 28.57142857142857
```

With...

```
.format(f, female_percent, m, round(male_percent,2),  n_binary, nonb_percent, other, other_percent,trans, trans_percent, unknown, unknown_percent)


Male: 2 cases 28.57
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding you question about how to clean up the code a bit, you can do this:

```
genders = ['Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female']

def count_gender(list_, elem):
    count = list_.count(elem)
    return '{}: {} cases {:.2%}\n'.format(elem, count, count/len(list_))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = ''
    for gender in ['Male', 'Female']:
        string += count_gender(genders, gender)
    print(string)
```

Also notice how `%` works in braces. You don't actually need to multiply by 100, it will print the truncated number in percentage.

Comment: How would I just put that in one function? and preferably without using the if __name__ == '__main__': line. Thank you.